# pyspeech 'input' function not working in python 2.7.7

Tags: python

[link to the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbQgZ.png)

I have written a code that works absolutely fine to make the program speak but i can't make it listen as it says that the speech module has no element 'input' function to allow it to listen to audio. if anyone could point out the problem or has found a way round this problem it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You could've just copied and pasted your code into here.